# What is the purpose of adding a ContextLoaderListener to the ServletContext?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

After reading several tutorials on replacing xml configuration with pure Java, there is one statement in the `Initializer` class that I don't understand:

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext;
        applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.register(Config.class);

        // What is the purpose of the following statement?
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(applicationContext));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher;
        dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

My application seems to run just fine without the `servletContext.addListener(...)` statement.

The official documentation inside `ServletContext` states, I kid you not:

```
/**
 * TODO SERVLET3 - Add comments
 * @param <T> TODO
 * @param t   TODO
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException    If [...]
 * @since Servlet 3.0
 */
public <T extends EventListener> void addListener(T t);
```

And the implementation inside `JspCServletContext` is actually empty:

```
@Override
public <T extends EventListener> void addListener(T t) {
    // NOOP
}
```

...So what exactly is the purpose of adding a `ContextLoaderListener` to the `ServletContext`?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the use of `ContextLoaderListener` is purely optional. It is used for binding your `ApplicationContext` and your `ServletContext` together explicitly.

Now, I would rephrase your question to:

> What is the purpose of adding a ContextLoaderListener to the **JspCServletContext?**

In your case, as you have noticed, even if you provide a `ContextLoaderListener` to your `ServletContext`, it will not be used. Thus, keep things simple, and remove the useless `ContextLoaderListener` here.